# Wat is exact difference between join and minus in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

IF there is 2 tables A and B .. wat is the exact diference between join and minus.?

and How minus operator actually work.

Comment: Create the tables and see for yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came here looking for an answer to which way would be the more efficient way of performing this query, but understanding how they can be similar is also an interesting question.

Sometimes an example is worth a thousand bits of theory.

Take 2 tables:

- customers: all of the people that have ever been customers
- collections: all of the people with accounts that have been sent to collections

Assuming we would like to send out Christmas cards, we probably want to not send them to people that have been bad customers. Based on that, we want to create a list of people that have not been sent to collections.

```sql
select name from customers
minus
select name from collections
```

This can be phrased in a very similar way that implies other query possibilities. We could say "customers that do not exist in the collections list" (use `exists`) or "customers that are not in the collections list" (use `in`)

```sql
select name 
from   customers
where  name not in (select name from collections)
```

This query has a lot in common with the previous, both will (theoretically) generate  a complete list of the `collections` and compare that as it scans the `customers` list.

There is a third way that this can be thought of, and that is with an outer join. We can ask for "a list of customers and their collections status, filter out those with a collections status"

```sql
select 
    cust.name 
from 
    customers cust
    left join collections coll on
        cust.name = coll.name
where 
    coll.name is null
```

The outer join will result in all `customers` and `null` in the `coll.name` position if nothing is found.

All three of these result in the same list of names being returned, the only difference being the way the underlying system constructs and manages the queries. In fact, I'm sure there are other variations that I have not considered.

While I could guess as to which would be more efficient, I leave that as an exercise for the reader ... mostly because I still don't' know.

Answer (score 0):

a JOIN finds rows that are **matched** between the two tables.

A MINUS finds rows that exist in the first table but **do not exist** in the second table.

Hemant K Chitale

Answer (score 0):

A join simply does an intersection between the tables.

A minus do a subtraction between tables finding rows that does  exists in table 1 but not in table 2.

[image]
[image]

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I also attempted to explain a join in a simple manner by intersection, but it is  wrong; join may even give a cross product.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the site! I do not know its existence! Thanks!